# What is the difference between /proc/net/tcp and /proc/pid/net/tcp

Tags: android, linux, networking

Can I assume that /proc/net/tcp is a sum of all the /proc/pid/net/tcp?
If not what are the differences?
Are the root/system tcp sessions managed separately?

Comment: Is it appropriate to also tag this 'linux', or has the Android kernel diverged significantly here?

Comment: yes a bit as in O we don't see all the processes?

Answer (score 5):

First one is statistics about the network interface (namely tcp) while pid is statistics from the process point of view.
If they're both running on the same network namespace, they're the same, if the process is running on a namespace where it has limits applied to its access to interfaces, it will only show those it has access to.

Comment: Not sure to understand your response. My question is really about the tcp/udp sessions. What do you call namespace? In android there is only one namespace?

Comment: This is more of a linux question than an android one. I am referring to network namespaces. A good read: https://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2016/04/10/network-namespaces/ . If you use /proc/net/tcp it will give all TCP connections, including system ones (AFAIK), the addition of <pid> is to only list the ones the process has access to. A network namespace is an instance of a network interface or routing table that are independent of one another.